# Custom model binder in EF do not load child entities in Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and when I use a custom model binder in an async call it throw me an exception because the child entity (Brand) is not loaded and mandatory. I'm using ninject, I updated to the latest version (
3.2.2.0)
Here's the code :

```
public class PlayerModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var context = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DbContext>();
            var id = ModelBinderHelpers.GetA<Guid>(bindingContext, "id");

            if (id == null || !id.HasValue)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");

            var entity = context.Set<Player>().Find(id);

            if (entity == null)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");

            return entity;
        }
    }
```

This will work :

```
public ActionResult Deactivate(Player player)
        {
            try
            {
                player.Deactivate();
                DbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var b = ex;
            }
            FlashBag.AddMessage(
                FlashType.Success,
                Strings.Player_DeactivatedSuccessfully);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But this does not work :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Deactivate(Player player)
        {
            try
            {
                player.Deactivate();
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var b = ex;
            }
            FlashBag.AddMessage(
                FlashType.Success,
                Strings.Player_DeactivatedSuccessfully);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038541/ef-validation-failing-on-update-when-using-lazy-loaded-required-properties)

I ended up doing this :

```
public class PlayerModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var context = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DbContext>();
            var id = ModelBinderHelpers.GetA<Guid>(bindingContext, "id");

            if (id == null || !id.HasValue)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");

            var entity = context.Set<Player>()
                .Include(x => x.Brand)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            if (entity == null)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");

            return entity;
        }
    }
```