# Entity Framework Error: The field "ForeignKey" is required EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity setup as follows

```
public class ExampleObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RelationID { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelationID")]
    public virtual RelationObj RelationObj { get; set; }
}
```

Later in my project I use this entity as follows

```
foreach (var rec in allRecs)
{
    db.ExampleObject.Attach(rec);
    rec.SomeValue = "TEST"
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

This throws a DbEntityValidationException "The field "RelationObj" is required"

I don't want to include the RelationObj when loading these records, that affects performance. Why is EF bothering to check the foreign relation object? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: You need to specify EntityState. db.Entry(rec).State = EntityState.Modified; By that way EF will know properties of object have changed.

Comment: This doesn't address the root problem. I am lazy loading my data, and I don't want to "Include" every related object when I all I need to do is update a simple record.

Comment: have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038541/ef-validation-failing-on-update-when-using-lazy-loaded-required-properties . It will shed light on what you want to do.

Comment: most likely RelationObj is null and therefore EF has to set RelationID to null, but it can't do that since this property is not nullable. you have to include the RelationObj for each entry since the FK is not nullable.

Comment: `RelationID` property type is `int`. EF will set relationship to required. just change property `RelationID ` type to `int?`

Answer (score 0):

First create the db, change the database on top of the script to match your db

```
USE [Breaz]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Relation]    Script Date: 6/29/2016 4:35:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Relation](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RelatedSomeValue] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Relation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Then create the next table, again change the db (Breaz):

```
USE [Breaz]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Example]    Script Date: 6/29/2016 4:34:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Example](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RelationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeValue] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Example] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Example]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Example_Relation] FOREIGN KEY([RelationID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Relation] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Example] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Example_Relation]
GO
```

Add a couple of rows of data into each table.

Add new item ADO.NET Entity Data Model, from your db and add both tables.  Name the edmx ExampleModel.  Get the (BreazEntities7) context (your context) from the Example.Context.cs file.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult YIndex()
    {
        using (BreazEntities7 db = new BreazEntities7())
        {
            var allRecs = db.Examples;
            foreach (var rec in allRecs)
            {
                rec.SomeValue = "TEST";
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
}
```

Here is the generated Example:

```
namespace Testy2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Example
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RelationID { get; set; }
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }

        public virtual Relation Relation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here id the generated Relation:

```
namespace Testy2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Relation
    {
        public Relation()
        {
            this.Examples = new HashSet<Example>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string RelatedSomeValue { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Example> Examples { get; set; }
    }
}
```